# Example where the partial derivatives exist in a nbhd of a point, but the function is discontinuous at that point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $$f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R},$$
and assume the partial derivatives of $f$ exist in a neighborhood of $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

We know that in case the partials are also bounded, then $f$ must be continuous at $x_0$.

What would be a simple example where the partials are not bounded, and the function is not continuous ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y)= \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0.$